# jqGrid onselectrow

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a jqGrid, and it gets populated fine. From the UI perspective,  one of the columns in the jqGrid is editable. How can I make one of the columns as editable (say like a text box)?

The reason is, in my case when the grid successfully loads, the UI is going to show one of the column's values as editable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to edit the column values directly in the grid, similarly to how you might in Excel, look into the [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing&s[]=inline) API:

- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing&s[]=inline

Answer (score 0):

In colmodel, you have to specify `editable: true`.Provide edit action link in `editURL:...` option of jqgrid.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the "id" of that column and then remove 'disabled' attribute on that.

for example -

```
$('#idofthatcolumn').removeAttr('disabled');
```

OR

```
$('#idofthatcolumn').removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `colmodel` you should specify editable as true i.e, `editable:true` and specify the `editUrl:'localhost:8080/yourApp'`

Also if you want to store it in the client side, then specify it as `editUrl:'clientArray'`